# Can't get relative password and ID from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

sorry if this isn't clear, or if this is simple, I'm a complete newbie at this.
I have this python code:

```
identer = input("Enter your Student ID... ")
passenter = input("Enter your password... ")

with open("pupil.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if identer != row["student_id"] or passenter != row["password"]:
            print("Wrong ID or Password, try again.")
        else:
```

The line `if identer != row["student_id"] or passenter != row["password"]:` is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Is there a solution here I'm blind to? Here is the CSV file, if it helps.

```
forename,surname,phone_no,email,password,student_id,account_balance,module1,module2

nathan,m,099099,ddd,12345,754,100,,

reg,beg,180,regb,0987,331,100,,

g,b,334,email,911,203,100,,
```

Edit:
This is my code with dictreader

```
    with open("pupil.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if identer != row[student_id] or passenter != row[password]:
                print("Wrong ID or Password, try again.")
            else:
```

This time it is throwing an error saying "KeyError: 754" 754 being the id

Comment: you have to use `csv.DictReader`

Comment: im still getting a keyerror on that line, is my syntax correct?

Comment: can you post your code with `csv.DictReader`

Comment: @naf You can edit the question with your new code, a [example] (as I can see, you didn't include the header row in the CSV -- or is there none?)

Comment: @user202729 i added the header row and the code with dictreader

Comment: That's not a [example]. It would definitely throw something like `NameError: student_id is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open("pupil.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if identer != row['student_id'] or passenter != row['password']:
            print("Wrong ID or Password, try again.")
        else:
            # code for handling the else case
```

You access dictionary elements with strings as key by putting quotes around you column names. I believe you were doing that previously already, but weren’t using the `DictReader`. This is how you access the rows with it.